# insert into with select + new information

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a sql query that can copy specific columns from a table and insert it in the same table + extra information for the other columns

Simply copying certain information would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE columnx = 'some value'
```

But I need to also insert some new information in column3. How can I do that?

I have the information that will go in "column3", I don't have to get it from an other table or source.

This is for a repeat appointment where basically all the information is the same except for date, planner and appointment_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the values are . . .

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, <value for column3>
FROM table
WHERE columnx = 'some value'
```